# polynom with numerator of 1

Tags: math-mode, polynom

Okay, so I just found out about the `polynom` package, and needless to say it is great. But I am having some issues with it. I am trying to do `1/(x+1)`, basically to show the power series expansion of it. I thought that possibly using the `stage` parameter would solve this problem, but no luck there. Any suggestions other than typing all of it out by hand?

Comment: I don't think the package can even compute divisions f/g when the degree of f is less than the degree of g.

Comment: I guess that would make sense, because why else would you be doing polynomial division, but basically I was trying to use it for a power series expansion thing.

Comment: You could try a symbolic algebra package for this. [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net), for example, does a pretty good job at exporting to LaTeX.